# Gradle exclude resources for one task but not for second

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to exclude resources for a task, but do not exclude them for a second task? Both are triggered from a third task like this:

```
task createBoth {
   dependsOn = [createFirst, createSecond]
}

task createFirst {
   sourceSets.main.resources.excludes = ['**/images']
}

task createSecond {
   sourceSets.main.resources.excludes = []
}
```

I tried to exclude in doFirst{} method, but it did not work. If run as a single task then it works fine. Both results are the same version of my Java project. Except they have a different main class and one does not need all images. So I want to create both files in a single run. Is it even possible?

---

Attempt 2:

```
task createSystemcheckJar(type: OneJar) {
   exclude('**/images/ads/images') // And some ohter combinations with stars
}
```

Same problem.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Create two separate jar files, one with images, and the other without them? What are these files you're talking about?

Comment: I create setup.exe and systemcheck.exe. Systemcheck is a single page that checks the system requirements. This check is run in setup, too. All images are in the directory "src/main/resources". Now I create two JARs in two gradle tasks. One for each EXE. I want to exclude some images from the JAR that is used to create the systemcheck.exe

Comment: The  you need to configure the jar task to exclude the files you don't want in the jar: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

Comment: Not working - see edit. Is it possible with OneJar task that extends the Jar task? Actually I found that this excludes only class files?

Comment: My solution: Copied OneJar and added custom parameter to exclude images